# MultipartProperties on Spring boot causing exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm working with Spring boot in my web app in order to expose REST api for uploading files.Everything worked like a charm until I wanted to configure my  application properties file to support bigger files by setting **multipart.maxFileSize**.I'm getting this exception :

> Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException.
>    Unable to start embedded Tomcat

This is my application.properties file :

```
server.port: 7000
multipart.maxFileSize=10Mb
```

**Update**

It was a syntax problem.Just replace "=" with ":"

Comment: Just posting the message from the exception isn't very helpful. The exception's stack trace and those of its causes should explain why the container couldn't start

Comment: Is it YAML or properties file. Note the different syntax.  If Indeed YAML, try: `multipart:
        maxFileSize: 10MB`. Otherwise: `server.port=7000`